# JSON.NET: How to obtain location of JSON token in initial stream, for better error reporting?

Tags: c#, json.net

It would be really nice to somehow get token's location in either original stream or manually built data structure, so that I can report to user exact location where things went wrong. Is this possible?
Please note I'm talking about getting that location right out of JsonToken instance and not about manual tracking, which may be not possible in case of multiple composed converters.

Code to illustrate question:

```cs
struct Foo
{
    public int answer;
}

// ... JsonConverter<Foo>

public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

    var theAnswerToken = obj["answer"];
    var theAnswer = theAnswerToken.Value<int>();
    if (theAnswer != 42)
        // How to get location of theAnswerToken in initial text here?
        throw new WrongAnswerException(theAnswerToken.Location() /* Does not exist now */);

    return new Foo { answer = theAnswer };
}
```

So when "answer" field is incorrect, you get exception with message like

```
Wrong answer at line 3, character 12, /path/to/foo/in/json/3/answer
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some examples? e.g. sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Totaly need a [mre]. With clear definition of valid in invalid input and their output. perhaps you are looking for a Json schema.

Comment: Like https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm

Comment: @DragandDrop Full JSON schema is an overkill here. And I doubt it can describe all possible conditions. I need just report nicely locations of some local nontrivial checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IJsonLineInfo`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_IJsonLineInfo.htm) interface to get information about approximate positioning in the JSON file.  This interface is implemented explicitly by both [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) and [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) so should allow you to generate more useful error messages.

For instance, if you modify `ReadJson()` as follows:

```
class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine((reader as IJsonLineInfo).FormatMessage("Entering ReadJson. ", reader.Path));

        // LineInfoHandling.Load ensures  line info is saved for all tokens while parsing (requires some additional memory).
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader, new JsonLoadSettings { LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Load }); 

        var theAnswerToken = obj["answer"];
        var theAnswer = theAnswerToken.Value<int>();
        if (theAnswer != 42)
            // How to get location of theAnswerToken in initial text here?
            throw new WrongAnswerException(theAnswerToken as IJsonLineInfo, "Wrong Answer");

        Debug.WriteLine((reader as IJsonLineInfo).FormatMessage("Exiting ReadJson. ", reader.Path));
        return new Foo { answer = theAnswer };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class WrongAnswerException : ApplicationException
{
    public WrongAnswerException() : base() { }
    public WrongAnswerException(IJsonLineInfo info, string message, string path = null) : base(info.FormatMessage(message, path)) { }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    // Adapted from https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonPosition.cs#L150
    // By https://github.com/JamesNK
    // This all looks terribly non-internationalized doesn't it? -dbc
    public static string FormatMessage(this IJsonLineInfo lineInfo, string message, string path = null)
    {
        // don't add a fullstop and space when message ends with a new line
        if (!message.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            message = message.Trim();

            if (!message.EndsWith('.'))
            {
                message += ".";
            }

            message += " ";
        }

        bool added = false;

        if (path != null)
        {
            message += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Path '{0}', ", path);
            added = true;
        }

        if (lineInfo != null && lineInfo.HasLineInfo())
        {
            message += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "line {0}, position {1}", lineInfo.LineNumber, lineInfo.LinePosition);
            added = true;
        }

        if (added)
            message += ".";

        return message;
    }
}
```

And pass in the following JSON:

```
{
  "answer": -100
}
```

Then the following exception is thrown:

```
WrongAnswerException: Wrong Answer. line 2, position 16.
   at FooConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, Boolean hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

Notes:

- When loading a `JObject` via `JObject.Load()` the default seems to be to include line info, whereas when deserializing a `JObject` via `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(JsonReader)` the default seems to be to not include line info.  I can't really explain the difference, but do note that, when reading large files, storing line info can cause substantial memory pressure, according to [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1938).

  Nevertheless in `ReadJson()` I set [`JsonLoadSettingsLineInfoHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings_LineInfoHandling.htm) to [`LineInfoHandling.Load`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_LineInfoHandling.htm) explicitly, for clarity.
- When a `JToken` hierarchy is loaded via `JToken.Load()`, experimentation indicates that the line position refers to the *end* of the relevant token, not the beginning.  If this is not what you want you may need to iterate through the object manually using `reader.Read()` and check the line info as you go.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aDF8za).